# How can I make a post sub link?

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls

I need to create a sub link for each post that will contain specific info about the post that I don't want displayed on the post page.

I am thinking of making a link as follows, but I'm not sure how to generate such a link and create a template file for it.

**E.g.**

Post URL: `www.domain.com/post-name`

Post Info URL: `www.domain.com/post-name/info`

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). As for the template, you can use hooks like [`single_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/) or just use conditional in your template, e.g. `if ( get_query_var( 'info' ) ) // your code`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will look into that!